# Error ejecutando medias queries

Tags: css, html5, responsive, mediaqueries

estoy desarrollando una pagina que saque de un sitio web que te da ideas para practicar el frontend. La pagina ya esta hecha, estan maquetados los tres tamaños (mobile, table, desktop) pero por alguna razon que no se la maquetacion para desktop me la toma cuando uso la consola del navegador pero cuando uso la pantalla completa vuelve a la maquetacion tablet. Les adjunto fotos para que se entienda mejor.
Esto es en el navegador(este es el diseño que uso para desktop con el header todo junto):
[image: Esto es cuando uso el navegador]

y esto cuando uso la pantalla completa(este es el diseño tablet con el header debajo del logo):
[image: Esto es cuando uso la pantalla completa]

Les adjunto el todo el codigo css y luego el html. Realmente no es la primera pagina que hago, ya hice varias e incluso ya tengo un par subidas a github pero esta vez no se cual es el error.

PD: NO ADJUNTE EL JAVASCRIPT POR QUE NO ME PARECIA NECESARIO YA QUE NO INFLUYE EN ESTO.

```css
:root {
    --venus-border:#F7CC7F;
    --mercury-border:#DEF4FC;
    --earth-border:#545BFE;
    --mars-border:#FF6A45;
    --jupiter-border:#ECAD7A;
    --saturn-border:#FCCB6B;
    --uranus-border:#65F0D5;
    --neptune-border:#497EFA;
}
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    /*font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;*/
    background-color: #070724;
    background-image: url("/assets/background-stars.svg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    /*background-position: 50vw left 0vh bottom;*/
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
    padding: 20px;
}
.logoPlaneta {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
}
/* MENU MOBILE */
.navPlanetas {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 105px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #070724;
    width: 100%;
    /*ESTA PROPIEDADES PARA QUE SE VE DE DONDE SALE*/
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: transform .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: transform .3s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: t;
    -moz-transform: t;
    -ms-transform: t;
    -o-transform: t;
}
.navPlanetas.active1 {
    transform: translate(100%,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.ul {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 30px;
}
.li {
    list-style: none;
}
.enlacePlaneta {
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
    padding: 20px 0px; 
}
.enlacePlaneta::after {
    content: url("/assets/icon-chevron.svg");
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 18px;
}
.spanCircle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color:red;
}
.mercury {
    background-color:#DEF4FC;
}
.venus {
    background-color: #F7CC7F;
}
.earth {
    background-color: #545BFE;
}
.mars {
    background-color: #FF6A45;
}
.jupiter {
    background-color: #ECAD7A;
}
.saturn {
    background-color: #FCCB6B;
}
.uranus {
    background-color: #65F0D5;
}
.neptune {
    background-color: #497EFA;
}

/* --------- FIN DE MENU MOBILE ---------------*/

/* --------- NAVEGADOR DE DATOS ---------------*/

.imagenes {
    display: none;
}
.navegadorDatos {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    width: 100%;
}
.ulDato {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.listaDato {
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    color: #C4C4C4;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 9px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
.listaDato:hover {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(237, 162, 73);
}

/*------- TEMPLATE -----------*/

.sectionInfo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;

}
.sectionImagenes {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}
.sectionImagenes img {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
.informacion {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.nombrePlaneta {
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.source {
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;

}
.wikiEnlace {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    font-weight:700;
    display: none;
}
img.busquedaIcono {
    margin: 0%;
}
img.imagenPlaneta2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.sectionImagenes .imagenPlanetaInternal {
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.articleInfoEspecifica {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}
.informacionEspecifica {
    border: thin solid #ebebeb;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
.infoFija {
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #C4C4C4;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.infoVariable {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.active {
    display: inline;
}
.numerosDato {
    display: none;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO MOBILE----------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO MOBILE----------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO MOBILE----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------------------------------------------MODO TABLET----------------------------------------*/

@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1300px) {
    
    .header {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .logoPlaneta {
        font-size: 25px;
    }    
    
    .navPlanetas {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ul {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 90%;
        gap: 0px;
    }
    .li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .enlacePlaneta {
        font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #e6e6e6;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-end;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: none;
        padding: 20px 0px; 
        font-size: 9px;
    }
    /*
    .enlacePlaneta:hover {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: rgb(237, 162, 73);
        border-radius: 0;
        border-bottom: none;
        padding-top: 17px;
    }
    */
    .enlacePlaneta::after {
        content: "";
    }
    .spanCircle {
        display: none;
    }
    .iconoBurguer {
        display: none;
    }
    .main {  
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .navegadorDatos {
        border-bottom: none;
        position: static;

    }
    .ulDato {
        flex-direction: column;
        grid-gap:20px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .listaDato {
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        border: thin solid #ebebeb;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .numerosDato {
        display: inline;
        opacity: 0.6;
        margin-right: 8px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .articleInfo {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .acaTemplateUno {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
    }
    .sectionInfo {
        width: 60%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 100px;
        gap: 25px;
    }
    .nombrePlaneta {
        margin: 0%;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .articleInfoEspecifica {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .informacionEspecifica {
        width: 100%;
        border: thin solid #ebebeb;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 5px 20px;
    }
    .infoFija {
        font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 9px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .infoVariable {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO TABLET----------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO TABLET----------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------FIN DEL MODO TABLET----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------------------------------------------MODO escritorio----------------------------------------*/
/*@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1300px)*/
@media all and (min-width:1301px) {
    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .header {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .logoPlaneta {
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }    
    .navPlanetas {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
        gap: 20px;
    }
    .li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .enlacePlaneta {
        border-bottom: none;
        font-size: 11px;
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    .enlacePlaneta:hover {
        color: white;
    }
    /*
    .enlacePlaneta::after {
        content: "";
    }
    */
    .spanCircle {
        display: none;
    }
    .iconoBurguer {
        display: none;
    }
    .sinTemplate {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
    }
    .sectionImagenes .imagenes {
        max-width:  initial;
    }
    img.imagenPlaneta2 {
        margin-top: -70px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .articleInfo {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .sectionInfo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .nombrePlaneta {
        font-size: 45px;
    }
    .navegadorDatos {
        border-bottom: none;
        position: static;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .ulDato {
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
    }
    .listaDato {
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 2.57143px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
    .articleInfoEspecifica {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        
    }
    .informacionEspecifica {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 250px;
    }
    .infoVariable {
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .numerosDato {
        display: initial;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@500&family=Spartan:wght@400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Mercury</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div>
      <p class="logoPlaneta">THE PLANETS</p>
    </div>

    <nav class="navPlanetas">
      <ul class="ul">
        <li class="li"><a href="mercury.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle mercury"></span> MERCURY</a>
        </li>

        <li class="li"><a href="venus.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle venus"></span> VENUS</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="earth.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle earth"></span> EARTH</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="mars.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle mars"></span> MARS</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="jupiter.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle jupiter"></span> JUPITER</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li"><a href="saturn.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle saturn"></span> SATURN</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li"><a href="uranus.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle uranus"></span> URANUS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li"><a href="neptune.html" class="enlacePlaneta"><span class="spanCircle neptune"></span> NEPTUNE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="assets/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="icono de menu mobile" class="iconoBurguer">
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <article class="sinTemplate">
      <section class="sectionImagenes">
        <img class="imagenes imagenPlaneta active" src="" alt="">
        <img class="imagenes imagenPlanetaStructure" src="" alt="">
        <img class="imagenes imagenPlaneta2" src="" alt="">
        <img class="imagenes imagenPlanetaInternal" src="" alt="">
      </section>
      <section class="articleInfo">
        <div class="acaTemplateUno">
          <nav class="navegadorDatos">
            <ul class="ulDato">
              <li class="listaDato datoOverview"><span class="numerosDato">01</span> OVERVIEW</li>
              <li class="listaDato datoStructure"><span class="numerosDato">02</span> STRUCTURE</li>
              <li class="listaDato datoSurface"><span class="numerosDato">03</span> SURFACE</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionInfo">
          <h2 class="nombrePlaneta"></h2>
          <div class="divInfo">
            <p class="informacion infoOverview active"></p>
            <p class="informacion infoStructure"></p>
            <p class="informacion infoSurface"></p>
          </div>
          <p class="source">Source:
            <a class="wikipediaOverview wikiEnlace active" href="" target="_blank">Wikipedia<img
                src="assets/icon-source.svg" alt="icono de busqueda" class="busquedaIcono">
            </a>
            <a class="wikipediaStructure wikiEnlace" href="" target="_blank">Wikipedia<img src="assets/icon-source.svg"
                alt="icono de busqueda" class="busquedaIcono">
            </a>
            <a class="wikipediaSurface wikiEnlace" href="" target="_blank">Wikipedia<img src="assets/icon-source.svg"
                alt="icono de busqueda" class="busquedaIcono">
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <article class="acaTemplateDos"></article>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  <template class="templateDos">
    <section class="articleInfoEspecifica">
      <div class="informacionEspecifica">
        <p class="infoFija">Rotation Time</p>
        <p class="TiempoRotacion infoVariable"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="informacionEspecifica">
        <p class="infoFija">Revolution Time</p>
        <p class="tiempoRevolucion infoVariable"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="informacionEspecifica">
        <p class="infoFija">Radius</p>
        <p class="radius infoVariable"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="informacionEspecifica">
        <p class="infoFija">Average temp</p>
        <p class="grados infoVariable"></p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya descubri el error, era por que lo estaba ejecutando en el live server(servidor local de visual studio code).